# Modified PHP PDO Login script still doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm learning php and OOP programming here. I have below working code I am trying to modify to prevent sql injection. Other people showed me the idea of how to use PDO. But I'm having difficulty getting it to work.

Basically this function is to pass the `$uid` and `$password` to check the user.
What am I doing wrong?

user_function.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {

        require_once 'db_connect.php';

        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    public function getUser($uid, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$uid' AND pswd = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $result;    

        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

modified code

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {

        require_once 'db_connect.php';

        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    public function getUser($uid, $password) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND pswd=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($uid, $password));
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }

}

?>
```

check for user (index.php)

```
require_once 'include/db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();


if ($tag == 'login') {

    $uid =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pswd']);

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUser($uid, $password);

    if ($user != false) {

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["user"]["id"] = $user["id"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: **You're using PDO. Why are you still trying to use mysql_* functions as well?**

Comment: It doesn't belong to your problem but never save passwords plaintext, md5 or sha1 hashed.
To provide a fair password security, please use the bcrypt algorithm or an algo with a similar strength. Please refer to your favorite search engine for some research. Keywords: bcrypt, random salt, [crypt function (look for Blowfish)](http://www.php.net/crypt).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO Login script not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059888/php-pdo-login-script-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using PDO, so you can't use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. You don't need to escape the parameters, as PDO will automatically escape them for you in your prepared query.

So, just call `getUser()` like this:

```
if ($tag == 'login') {

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUser( $_POST['id'], $_POST['pswd']);

    ... etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the point entirely of PDO. With properly prepared queries using placeholderse, you do not have to do ANY escaping yourself.

As well, mysql_real_escape_string() depends on there being an active database connection established with `mysql_connect()`. Without that, your m_r_e_s() will not work and will return a boolean false for "failed". You then try to use those false values in your query.

DB connections established by PDO are not shareable with mysql_*(), mysqli_*(), etc... Each of those libraries mantains their own independent connection pool.